# how to Concat data value in sql server

Tags: sql-server, database

I have table A in database but I want to know how to change or concat it to table B with a SQL command in SQL Server like this:

[image]

Comment: Seems like you are looking for JOIN

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL Server 2017+ you can use `STRING_AGG` to achieve this:

```
SELECT  [Personal Code],
        STRING_AGG(Unit, ' / ') AS Unit
  FROM  [Table A]
  GROUP BY [Personal Code]
```

Output:

```
Personal Code   Unit
981203030       Albani / Italy / England
981203031       France / Spain / Denmark
981203033       Russia / Peru
```

Here's the [working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cd07ff/3) for this.

You can then insert this directly into `Table B`:

```
INSERT INTO [Table B] ([Personal Code], Unit)
    SELECT  [Personal Code],
            STRING_AGG(Unit, ' / ')
      FROM  [Table A]
      GROUP BY [Personal Code]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using lower version of MSSQL

```
Select distinct ST2.[Personal Code], LTrim(substring((Select ' / '+ ST1.unit  AS [text()]
                                From taba ST1 Where ST1.[Personal Code]= ST2.[Personal Code]
                                ORDER BY ST1.[Personal Code] For XML PATH ('')), 3, 1000)) Unit
From taba ST2
```